# Scientific notation wrongly converts to numbers

Tags: r, scientific-notation

I've got a table of data with scientific notation numbers such as `1.1e-07`.
When I try to convert these numbers to normal numbers with as.numeric, R gives me wrong numbers, like:

```
1.1e-07:   5977  
1.4e-06:   5633
```

etc.

How can I fix this?

**Update:** thanks, it really was about factors.

Comment: What is the type of the input data? If it is factor then I would expect your wrong result. Where do you get the data from?

Comment: Almost certainly they were imported as factors.

Answer (score 3):

Your numbers are most probably defined as factors. This will result in `as.numeric` not returning the "value" of the input but the factor level sequence number.

```
x <- as.factor(c(1.1e-7, 2e-8)) ## convert two numbers to factors

as.numeric(x)
[1] 2 1
```

To solve this problem make sure you read in the data not as factors from you data source.

Note that a quick and dirty solution would be something like

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))
[1] 1.1e-07 2.0e-08

format(as.numeric(as.character(x)), scientific = F)
[1] "0.00000011" "0.00000002"
```

By the way, scientific notation is standard in R. `format` casts the numbers as character.